# Web-server after another computer

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, proxy

I have main computer with 2 network cards: one from internet, another -> to next computer with web server. DNS points several domains to my static IP, I want to serve them by second computer. How to manage all this. I guess I need some proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

DNAT (port forwarding) should work if you only want to put one webserver behind the bastion host. This would be my choice for a linux bastion host with a single webserver behind it.

A quick google should give you a recipe.

You could also use a reverse proxy or proxy passing, which is probably the route I'd take if I wanted multiple webservers behind the bastion.

Answer (score 0):

Enable IP forwarding and NAT static_ip:80 to next_computer:80 in iptables.

In /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <static_internet_ip> --dport 80 -j dnat --to-destination <next_computer_ip>:80
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse proxy would also be a good solution if you wish to cache some content and have the actual webserver less loaded